# How to replace only one part of a sub string from a string containing more than one similar parts?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datagridview

I might have not stated the question as what I would like to. Please consider below scenario.

**Scenario:**
I am implementing a Search/Replace functionality in my C# Win Form application. This feature will have the option to replace a substring that "starts with" or "ends with" a certain value. For example:

- A string contains `"123ABCD"`. Replacing `"123"` with `"XYZ"` should produce: `"XYZABCD"`
- A string contains `"ABCD123"`. Replacing `"123"` with `"XYZ"` should produce: `"ABCDXYZ"`

Both of these features are working fine. My problem is when the string contains `"123ABCD123"`. Both operations return the wrong value when using `"XYZ"`.

- "starts with" produces `"XYZABCDXYZ"`, instead of `"XYZABCD"`
- "ends with" produces `"XYZABCDXYZ"` instead of `"ABCDXYZ"`

Can anyone give me an idea how to achieve that?

Thanks !!!

**Code Snippet:**

```
if (this.rbMatchFieldsStartedWith.Checked)
{
    if (caseSencetive)
    {
        matched = currentCellValue.StartsWith(findWhat);
    }
    else
    {
        matched = currentCellValue.ToLower().StartsWith(findWhat.ToLower());
    }
}
else if (this.rbMatchFieldsEndsWith.Checked)
{
    if (caseSencetive)
    {
        matched = currentCellValue.EndsWith(findWhat);
    }
    else
    {
        matched = currentCellValue.ToLower().EndsWith(findWhat.ToLower());
    }
}

if (matched)
{
    if (replace)
    {
        if (this.rbMatchWholeField.Checked)
        {
            currentCell.Value = replaceWith;
        }
        else
        {
            currentCellValue = currentCellValue.Replace(findWhat, replaceWith);
            currentCell.Value = currentCellValue;
        }
        this.QCGridView.RefreshEdit();
    }
    else
    {
        currentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks every one for your concern. But for the time being, I am using Neil Moss's answer and it seems fine so far. Thank you all once again.

Comment: In addition, thanks to @Leigh for making the question much more readable and understandable. Cheers !!!

Comment: TVM - I went with the simplest solution to fix your exact case as at now. If you need a more flexible search/replace function later on, I think RegEx would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the replacement method dependent on the search mode.

Replace the line

```
currentCellValue = currentCellValue.Replace(findWhat, replaceWith);
```

with

```
if (this.rbMatchFieldsStartedWith.Checked)
{
    // target string starts with findWhat, so remove findWhat and prepend replaceWith
    currentCellValue = replaceWith + currentCellValue.SubString(findWhat.Length);
}
else
{
    // target string end with findWhat, so remove findWhat and append replaceWith.
    currentCellValue = currentCellValue.SubString(0, currentCellValue.Length - findWhat.Length) + replaceWith;
}

currentCell.Value = newValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good one for [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

It is supported by .NET, and also has a replacement syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to try a replacement method without using regex.
(Regex could be the right way to do it, but it was funny to find an alternative)

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "123ABCD123";  // String to change
    string rep = "XYZ";          // String to replace
    string find = "123";         // Replacement string
    bool searchStart = true;     // Flag for checkbox startswith 
    bool searchEnd = true;       // Flag for checkbox endswith
    bool caseInsensitive = true; // Flag for case type replacement

    string result = test;         
    int pos = -1;
    int lastPos = -1;

    if(caseInsensitive == true)
    {
        pos = test.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        lastPos = test.LastIndexOf(find, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    else
    {
        pos = test.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        lastPos = test.LastIndexOf(find, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    result = test;
    if(pos == 0 && searchStart == true)
    {
        result = rep + test.Substring(find.Length);
    }
    if(lastPos != 0 && lastPos != pos && lastPos + find.Length == test.Length && searchEnd == true)
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, lastPos) + rep;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all let's trace your scenario assuming:

- string to work on is 123ABCD123
- starts with is checked.
- aim is to replace "123" with "XYZ"

by just reading your code. We hit `if (this.rbMatchFieldsStartedWith.Checked)` and which evaluates to true. So we step in that block. We hit `matched = currentCellValue.StartsWith(findWhat);` and `matched = true`. We continue with `if (matched)` condition which also evaluates to `true`. After that `if (replace)` evaluates to `true`. Finally we make the last decision with `if (this.rbMatchWholeField.Checked)` which evaluates to `false` so we continue with `else` block:

```
currentCellValue = currentCellValue.Replace(findWhat, replaceWith);
currentCell.Value = currentCellValue;
```

First line in this block replaces all the occurrences of `findWhat` with `replaceWith`, namely all the occurrences of 123 with XYZ. Of course this is not the desired behaviour. Instead of `Replace` you must use a function that replaces just the first or the last occurrence of the string according to the input of course.

Comment: agreed with you. And this is my problem. I can't find any starting point about writing the function.

Comment: I will try to give a starting point but before that what if the string is 123AB123CD123. Will it be XYZABCD?